# Distributional Fourier transform of $\arctan$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I understand that for a Schwartz function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, its Fourier transform is another Schwartz function, while if $f$ was a bounded continuous function, then in general its Fourier transform is a distribution. In particular, one can talk about the *support* of a distribution.

**Question:** Consider the bounded function $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. Is its distributional Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ a compactly supported distribution?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f'$ equals $-i\xi \hat{f}(\xi)$ and on the other hand you can calculate it explicitely (essentially $\exp(-|\xi|))$. Another way to see that the Fourier transform of $f'(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ does not have compact support uses the inversion formula and the fact that the Fourier transform of a distribution with compact support is an entire function which is not true for $f'$ (which has singularities at $\pm i$).