# Distributional Fourier transform of $x \arctan(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I want to find the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f(x) =  x \arctan(x)$ in the sense of distributions. It is known that for any $\varphi \in \mathscr{S\mathbb{(R}})$, $\langle \hat f,\varphi\rangle = \langle f,\hat \varphi\rangle$. So we get
\begin{align*}
\langle \hat f,\varphi\rangle &=\int_\mathbb{R} x \arctan(x) \, \hat\varphi(x) \,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}x \arctan(x) \int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(k)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm dk  \,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}x \arctan(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm dx \right)\varphi(k) \,\mathrm dk
\end{align*}

We should rewrite $x \arctan(x)$ in exponential form in order to solve integral? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does $*$ mean ordinary multiplication or convolution?

Comment: Do you know the Fourier transform of $\arctan(x)$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yep, just ordinary mult

Comment: @md2perpe No I don't know distributional Fourier transform of arctan(x). Can you pls give a hint how to solve it?

Comment: I simplified the notations that weren't completely coherent

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844566/distributional-fourier-transform-of-arctan

Comment: I would evaluate the second derivative of $x\arctan(x)$ and try to find the Fourier transform of that!

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the Fourier transform of $f(x)\in L^1$ as

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$$

First, note that with $X(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\arctan(x)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{Xg\}(k)&=-i\frac{d}{dk}\mathscr{F}\{g\}(k)\\\\
&=-i\frac{d}{dk}\left(\text{PV}\left(\frac{i\pi}{k}e^{-|k|}\right)\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

where the derivative is taken in the sense of distributions and wehre we used [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911029/fourier-transform-of-frac-arctanxx/1911174#1911174) to arrive at the Fourier transform of the arctangent.